# Aleph/Clojure - How to insert custom headers in the web socket upgrade response?

Tags: clojure, websocket, aleph

I am trying to port one of our services to Aleph. The service uses a web socket server (currently runs on http-kit). One of the things I require is the ability to add some custom http headers in the response during the websocket Upgrade process.  Do you see a way I could do that?

To elaborate, I need to inspect the `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions` header value from the client request, and based on that add a response header during the upgrade process. And similarly need to check the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header in the request, and add the same back to the response if the protocol is what I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `websocket-connection` & `websocket-client` accepts a `:headers` keywords parameter. The documentation is [here](http://aleph.io/codox/aleph/aleph.http.html).

Comment: I am aware of that. But it does not say anything beyond 'the headers will be included in the handshake'. I want to be able to inspect the values of a couple of request headers during the upgrade, and based on those values, add some headers back to the response.
Does the above :headers keyword you mentioned do the job of simply including whatever headers I pass (during the connect) in the response?

Comment: I can inspect the headers prior to calling the websocket-connection fn, and stuff my custom response headers in the :headers keyword. Would that mean that Aleph would pass back those headers to the client during the handshake? @muhuk